# How can I integrate a QuadraticSpeedDependentForce Component on OpenModelica?

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I'm working on a Modelica model where I'm using the `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.QuadraticSpeedDependentForce` component to model forces. The force magnitude (`f_nominal`) is calculated based on a coefficient `C`, a parameter `A`, and a reference speed `vRef`.

```
Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.QuadraticSpeedDependentForce force(
    final useSupport=true,
    final f_nominal= C * A,
    final ForceDirection=false,
    final v_nominal=vRef)
    annotation (Placement(visible=true, transformation(origin={-62, 56}, extent={{50, -40}, {70, -20}}, rotation=0)));
```

`C`, `A` and `vRef` are presented as:

```
Real C(unit="kN/m2");
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Area A(start = 1);
constant Modelica.Units.SI.Velocity vRef = 1 "Reference velocity";
```

I have an integer input signal `inSignal` that is used to update a coefficient `C` dynamically based on a matrix `C_matrix`. Here's how I'm updating `C`:

```
indicator = inSignal + 1;
C = C_matrix[indicator, 2];
```

`indicator` and `C_matrix` are presented as:

```
Integer indicator "C matrix position indicator";
parameter Real C[2, 2] = {{1,0},{2,0.5}]
```

When I simulate the code I get: `Component f_nominal of variability parameter has binding 'C * A[<fDrag, fDrag>]' of higher variability continuous.`

I have as reference the vehicle component `Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Components.Vehicle` of Modelica's library.

I'd appreciate any help on how to ensure the proper integration of the component. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is, that you try to compute a parameter (be definition constant for the time of a simulation) from a variable. Namely, you try to compute the parameter `f_nominal` from the variable `C`. This is why you get the error message basically saying `C` has a higher variability than `f_nominal`.

For more explanation on variability, read https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/equations/variables/.

There are some potential solutions to the issue you are having. I think the feasible ones are pointed out here: [Define Model Parameter as Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43128203/define-model-parameter-as-variable). At first sight, it seems that replacing the parameter `f_nominal` with an input seems to be the most simple solution. The result of this would be:

```
model QuadraticSpeedDependentForceInput "Quadratic dependency of force versus speed with 'f_nominal' as input"
  extends Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Interfaces.PartialForce;

  parameter Boolean ForceDirection=true
    "Same direction of force in both directions of motion";
  parameter Modelica.Units.SI.Velocity v_nominal(min=Modelica.Constants.eps) "Nominal speed";

  Modelica.Units.SI.Velocity v "Velocity of flange with respect to support (= der(s))";

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput f_nominal "Nominal force (if negative, force is acting as load in positive direction of motion)"
    annotation (Placement(transformation(extent={{-140,-20},{-100,20}}), iconTransformation(extent={{-140,-20},{-100,20}})));

equation 
  v = der(s);
  if ForceDirection then
    f = -f_nominal*(v/v_nominal)^2;
  else
    f = -f_nominal*smooth(1, if v >= 0 then (v/v_nominal)^2 else -(v/v_nominal)^2);
  end if;
  annotation (
    Icon(coordinateSystem(preserveAspectRatio=true, extent={{-100,
            -100},{100,100}}), graphics={
          Line(points={{-60,50},{-60,-40}}, color={192,192,192}),
          Line(points={{-75,-30},{75,-30}}, color={192,192,192}),
        Line(
          points={{-60,-30},{-40,-28},{-20,-22},{0,-10},{20,6},{40,26},{58,52}},
          color={0,0,127},
          smooth=Smooth.Bezier)}),     Documentation(info="<html>
<p>An modified version of 
<a href=\"Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.QuadraticSpeedDependentForce\">Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.QuadraticSpeedDependentForce</a> 
with <code>f_nominal</code> as input instead of a parameter.</p>
</html>"),
    uses(Modelica(version="4.0.0")));
end QuadraticSpeedDependentForceInput;
```